# ppt and pptx files are corrupted when trying to stream from asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to stream documents from a server location to an asp.net website.  All document types work as expected apart from powerpoint ppt and pptx files.
When these are streamed the message "powerpoint found a problem with content in [filename]"
However if I selected Save rather than open then open the doc it all works ok.

my code is as follows

WCF SERVICE

```
//get doc from server and convert to bytearray
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, 
                                         FileMode.Open, 
                                         FileAccess.Read, 
                                         FileShare.Read);
byte[] myFileByte = new byte[(int)myFileStream.Length];
myFileStream.Read(myFileByte, 0, (int)myFileStream.Length);
myFileStream.Close();
```

ASP.NET Web App

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.BinaryWrite(getDoc.DownloadData); // [byte array ]
Response.End();
```

I have tried using response.flush but that stops everything from opening.
anyone any ideas as this has stumped me for a few days now.
Thanks

Comment: UPDATE.After further investigation this issue is only happening in IE.  I have got IE 11 and the files are Powerpoint 2010.  this works in Chrome.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Further Update. By unticking the trust options within the installation of powerpoint on my machine all files now open correctly.

This isn't ideal as I'll have to add a help section to the website to inform my company user base they have to do this but it is a work around.

Surely there must be a way to do it in code??